# About retaining game layer in shared instance

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I found in internet sample of Multi level application, (something like cut the rope when you select levels)

There is shared instance object, NSObject which is games brain, where logic of the game is stored

```
    @interface GameData : NSObject {

    ObjLevelInfo *levelInfoArray[MAX_LEVEL_NUMBER]; // array to store level info
    int _curLevelIndex;         // current playing level number, local
    int _curScore;              // current score, local
    CCLayer *_curGameLayer;     // link to current Game Layer, local

}

@property (nonatomic) int curLevelIndex;             // current playing level number
@property (nonatomic) int curScore;                  // current score
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCLayer *curGameLayer; // link to current Game Layer
```

curGameLayer is used to store current running layer.

And also several game scene CCLayer classes.
In init method of these classes I found

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {

        //make sure you call this to correctly link GameData with this game layer
        [[GameData sharedInstance] setCurGameLayer:self];
...
```

this will happen each time new scene will load, I wonder if it may be source of leak? does scene will be removed from memory when new scene will load while game data has retained it?

Update:

I have found nice tutorial here http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/files/cocos2d-essential-reference-sample/Strategies_for_Accessing_Other_Nodes.html#2687105_StrategiesforAccessingOtherNodes-AccessingtheCurrentlyRunningSceneviaDirector.So if I remove `@property (nonatomic, retain) CCLayer *curGameLayer;` property and also `[[GameData sharedInstance] setCurGameLayer:self];` this linking, and insted in Game data use

```
CCScene* runningScene = [CCDirector sharedDirector].runningScene;
MyScene* gameScene;
```

and use something like `(MyProgressBar *)[gameScene getChildByTag:progressBarTag];` to access currently running scenes nodes, will it still be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will stay in memory unless game layer is explicitly released. If ARC were enabled it would suffice to set that property to nil. This is a grave danger of using this global game state approach, and teaching that approach to beginners is a terrible idea. As a rule of thumb one should never retain nodes in objects that are not nodes themselves, and never retain any parent or sibling nodes, only children or grandchildren nodes. This is to avoid retain cycles.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. It is very bad, unfortunately I did very huge work in that direction :(  Is there a way to add some code, checks and corrections to run this scheme incorrect scheme correctly? ARC is enabled in my project.